# How to Redirect user to Previous URL After registering in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Using the built in Auth system in Laravel 5.6, I have multiple pages on my website where I need a user to register or login to perform an action such as making a purchase, etc...

I have my login redirecting back to the previous page the user was on prior to login, but can't seem to get this to work with registering.

**Example of what I'm looking for:**

1. User clicks register from Page X.
2. User goes to register page
3. User is then redirected back to Page X instead of homepage
4. User is always redirected back to the Page they where previously on.

**Here is my RegisterController.php:**

```
//protected $redirectTo = '/'; (Originally Returning Back To Home)

//WHAT I'M USING NOW TO TRY AND REDIRECT BACK TO PREVIOUS PAGE

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
    return url()->previous();
    }

// Guards/Redirects user to home if logged in and tries to access register page again.

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    } 


// If users email exists in my transaction database, I show them a Thank you message upon registering. And Still want to redirect them back to previous page.

    public function registered($request, $user) {
        $where = [
            ['customer_email', $user->email],
            ['user_id', null],
        ];

        if (Transaction::where($where)->exists()) {
            Transaction::where($where)->update(['user_id' => $user->id]);

            return url()->previous()
                ->with('success', 'Thank you for your previous transaction! Go to your Profile to review your transaction history.');
        }
    }
```

Here is how I got this working with the Login Controller, but didn't work with the register controller.

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if (session('link')) {
        $myPath     = session('link');
        $loginPath  = url('/login');
        $previous   = url()->previous();

        if ($previous = $loginPath) {
            session(['link' => $myPath]);
        }else{
            session(['link' => $previous]);
        }
    }
    else{
        session(['link' => url()->previous()]);
    }
    return view('auth.login');
}

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect(session('link'));      
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The link you said is a duplicate is what I used to get the login redirecting back to previous page correctly. What I'm asking is how would I do the same for users after registration.

Comment: Is page X just a view? Are you passing any data to it?

Comment: So from what you have said user is on /page1, then goes to /register and fills out registration and submits.  If registration is successful you want them to go back to /page1?

Comment: @ColinMD yes that is correct. Whatever page the user access the registration page from, is the page I would like them to return back too.

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane Yes, page X is just a view. Example the About Us view/page. I'm passing data to most of my pages via the database and foreach loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you can do it in a similar way to your login controller.

You will first need to create the below function in your Register Controller to override the default and save the URL into the session

```
/**
* Show the application registration form.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    if (session('link')) {
        $myPath     = session('link');
        $registerPath  = url('/register');
        $previous   = url()->previous();

        if ($previous = $registerPath) {
            session(['link' => $myPath]);
        }else{
            session(['link' => $previous]);
        }
    } else{
        session(['link' => url()->previous()]);
    }
    return view('auth.register');
}
```

Then create the following function, again in the Registration Controller

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return redirect(session('link'))->with('success', 'Thank you for your previous transaction! Go to your Profile to review your transaction history.');
}
```

You may also want to set a default route in there incase they access the register form direct. So

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if(session('link')){
        return redirect(session('link'))->with('success', 'Thank you for your previous transaction! Go to your Profile to review your transaction history.');
    }
    return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Thank you for your previous transaction! Go to your Profile to review your transaction history.');
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Comment: Hi ColinMd, i use exactly the same code and i have this error when i submit the register form. 
ErrorException
Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Any idea why ?
Thanks

Comment: Found, you can not use redirect in the function redirectTo(), you can do return 'home';